# Scraping Gap Up & Gap Down tables on Barchart with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table, bar-chart

I've been trying for many hours to find a class or table ID for the following link on Barchart: [Gap Up & Gap Down](https://www.barchart.com/stocks/performance/gap/gap-up?orderBy=gapUpPercent&orderDir=desc)

I've inspected the elements & source code with devloper tools; as well as looked at the sources but not find what I'm looking for. I'm new to this thank you

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.barchart.com/stocks/performance/gap/gap-up?orderBy=gapUpPercent&orderDir=desc'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.text)
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve data: {response.status_code}")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the given website the stocks data is coming in different request and they are loading it dynamically using some scripts.
Even if we check in the page source there is nothing related to the stocks data so you are not able to find class or id attributes.

When we do inspect we can see the data in HTML tags but when we try to write XPATHs for the same it will not work as this HTML data is constructed dynamically.(Open inspect and try to search any stock name, you can find the data under set-class).

The data is coming in https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/quotes/get?lists=stocks.us.price_gaps.advances.overall&orderDir=asc&fields=symbol%2CsymbolName%2ClastPrice%2CpriceChange%2CpercentChange%2CgapUp%2CgapUpPercent%2ChighPrice%2ClowPrice%2Cvolume%2CtradeTime%2CsymbolCode%2CsymbolType%2ChasOptions&orderBy=symbolName&meta=field.shortName%2Cfield.type%2Cfield.description%2Clists.lastUpdate&hasOptions=true&page=1&limit=100&raw=1 this request as JSON data and they are dynamically constructing HTML data and showing in website.

To make the above requests we need to send some headers and cookies, cookies are mandatory header here, so we need to understand how they are generating the cookies and pass them in the request to get the data.

Comment: Hello Bhaskar, I'm trying 2 different methods on getting cookies loading from the website. First is done manually by using cookies = {
    'laravel_token': (''),

    'XSRF-TOKEN': (''),

    'laravel_session': ('')
    }

# Make the GET request to the API
response = requests.get(formatted_url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the JSON response
    data = response.json()
    # Now you can process the data
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve data: {response.status_code}")

Comment: second method for getting cookies is 
import requests

# Initialize a session object
session = requests.Session()okies is # Make the GET request using the session
response = session.get(formatted_url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the JSON response
    data = response.json()
    print("Data retrieved successfully:", data)
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve data: {response.status_code}")
Both methods I recieve the Failed to retrieve data: 401 error

Comment: Hi James Beusse, if you want to take cookies manually please copy the request with copy as curl in network debugging.

But taking cookies manually may not work every time, so we need to findout how these cookies are generating or in which requests they are coming.

Some tokens are coming in https://www.barchart.com/stocks/performance/gap/gap-up?orderBy=gapUpPercent&orderDir=desc please check